# php parse xml unknown nr. of tags

Tags: php, xml

i have to parse xml files of the following format

```
<row>
  <field name="ID">123</field>
  <field name="Number">987</field>
  <field name="Title">Awesome name of thing</field>
  ....
</row>
```

The amount of tags is unknwon, the result should be an associative array like so:

```
'ID' => 123
'Number' => 987
'Title' => 'Awesome Name of thing'
```

Could please point me someone into the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: The answer is already on SO: [How to get XML data as an associative array with attributes as key in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15110695/1305969).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is as simple as you say, then SimplXML can do it quite easily.

```
$xmlText = <<< XML
<row>
<field name="ID">123</field>
<field name="Number">987</field>
<field name="Title">Awesome name of thing</field>
</row>
XML;

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlText);

$data = [];
foreach ( $doc->field as $fields)   {
    $data[(string)$fields['name']] = (string)$fields;
}

print_r($data);
```

The main thing to watch out for is that when using things like `$fields['name']` is that this is the attribute of the element (i.e. ID), but this needs to be cast to a string to get this as a string and not an object.  Same with the $fields at the end, this is a SimpleXMLElement object, the cast converts it to a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $simple = '<row>
  <field name="ID">123</field>  
  <field name="Number">987</field>
  <field name="Title">Awesome name of thing</field>
</row>  ';


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($simple);
  $xml_data = (array) $xml ;
              $data['id'] =   $xml_data['field'][0];
              $data['Number'] =   $xml_data['field'][1];
              $data['Title'] =   $xml_data['field'][2];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Comment: this is not exactly what i need, because i do not know the exact structure ... i need a kind of foreach to loop over the fields and populate them into the array.